Emulator top bar is cropping when using VS Code and flutter
Trying flutter for the first time. When I launch my flutter app in emulator, its app bar is not visible as it is being cropped. See screenshot below.

At first, I thought there is some issue with app but when I saw the following, it shows that the app is successfully launched. It is just being cut off/cropped from the top. How to make whole emulator visible?

